# How to locate the abnormal position in a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to get the coordinate of value that it has differed from other values in that column. Here is a simple example of the array.

```
arr = np.ones((4,4))
arr[:2, :2] = 0
```

This will give you a 4 by 4 matrix, and the value at [2,0], [2,1], [3,0], [3,1] are considered abnormal since it has a different value than other values in that column. ----  I want to get those coordinates as the output.

I have tried some ways to find the number of unique values in that column and locate the columns where include more than two values. However, it is hard for me to get the rows.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What do you define as abnormal? With `image1 = np.ones((4, 4)); image1[:2, :2] = 0`, the first two columns have an equal number of each element, so without any other constraints you cannot say which is correct.

Comment: so if you think that 4x4 as a square. and 1 as black, 0 as white

that square will be filled with black excpet the part where 0s are. So i want to get the position where stick out from the white body (right half of the square)

Comment: Ok - so you will have a particular value you know is good, and you're just looking for when it does not equal that?

Comment: Not actually. I want to know the part where it is part of the body but stick out from it.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a few more examples?

Comment: sure. 
iimage1[:3, :1] = 0 =====> (0,3)
image1[:, :1] = 0 =======> no abnormal
image1[:3, -1] = 0 ======> (3,3)

These will be desired part to detect

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

The question here is what is it "normal" for you. The way I understood it you give your array and the "normal Value" for you (in your example is 1).

```
def oddColumnValues(numpyArray,normalValue):
    oddValuesList = []
    for column in range(numpyArray.shape[1]):
        oddValuesList += [(row, column, value) for (row, value) in enumerate(numpyArray[:,column]) if value!=normalValue]
    return oddValuesList
```

The function returns a list with tuples containing the coordinates of the cell with an odd value, and the odd value itself (row, column, value)

In your above example:

```
image1 = np.ones((4,4))
image1[0:3,0] = 0

oddColumnValues(image1,1) --> [(0, 0, 0.0), (1, 0, 0.0), (2, 0, 0.0)]
```

Comment: thank you for your help, however, those coordinates are where 0s are. I want the out put to be (3,0)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get abnormal values in every column, you can do something like this:

```py
indexes = []
for j,col in enumerate(image1.T):
    unique,counts = np.unique(col,return_counts=True)
    for abnormal in unique[counts<2]:
        for i in np.where(col==abnormal)[0]:
            indexes.append([j,i])
```

defining abnormal to be less than 2 occurrences.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, your answer gives an error

DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

Comment: You are right, I was not looping for each abnormal value. Thank you